# Is it possible to change the GPU in HP G42-388TX?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, swap

I was just wondering if I could swap my GPU (AMD Radeon Mobility HD 5000 Series) with a better one. But I don't know whether the GPU is soldered on or not or is it possible to swap? I don't want to risk to disassemble to check it as I don't have a thermal paste to put it back on together. Plus, HP Chat support seems unresponsive.

Comment: on laptops you can usually "change the graphics card" by replacing the whole motherboard with a newer one if one exists. With HP's terrible support of legacy products, you'll be lucky if you can find somebody to do even that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is No, it cannot be swapped (yes you can try to swap, but a DIY approach will be needed), yes it is soldered onto the PCB/MOBO.

Long answer (which could give you false hope, and is doable by people with a lot of time on their hands):

Disassemble your laptop, then find the MoBo's PART NO. and REPLACEMENT PART NO., Google/eBay/China for few hours, then find out that:

This where you can find all your HP part numbers without ripping everything apart:
http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?type=PROD&SearchText=XV691PA

As you can see the only available MOBO is "PC BOARD - 615579-001" when we search for this it turns out all of these laptops use this MoBo's replacement number, just the question you need to seek if there is a alternative build for each of these models, and if so will it fit in your laptop's case.

```
XT828PA HP G42-372TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT828PA
XT826PA HP G42-370TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT826PA
XT829PA HP G42-373TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT829PA
XT825PA HP G42-369TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT825PA
XT824PA HP G42-368TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT824PA
XU767PA HP G42-383TX NOTEBOOK PC - XU767PA
XT822PA HP G42-366TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT822PA
XU768PA HP G42-384TX NOTEBOOK PC - XU768PA
XU769PA HP G42-385TX NOTEBOOK PC - XU769PA
LG290PA HP G42-397TX NOTEBOOK PC - LG290PA
XT827PA HP G42-371TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT827PA
XV731PA HP G42-390TX NOTEBOOK PC - XV731PA
XT871PA HP G42-379TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT871PA
LG291PA HP G42-398TX NOTEBOOK PC - LG291PA
XT870PA HP G42-378TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT870PA
XU766PA HP G42-382TX NOTEBOOK PC - XU766PA
XV691PA HP G42-388TX NOTEBOOK PC - XV691PA
XT823PA HP G42-367TX NOTEBOOK PC - XT823PA
XP563PA HP G42-353TX NOTEBOOK PC - XP563PA
```

Answer (score 0):

It 'probably' can be swapped...with a 'compatible' motherboard etc.  The best thing to do if you are not sure is to bring it to a qualified computer repair/replace establishment.  It's not a good idea to experiment with hardware situations like this.  ;-)  Believe me I have done it and paid.

Comment: So do you have any source on this or is it mere speculation? Because I’d say it isn’t possible. Why would it be? You’d need a graphics card module to swap. You can’t just change the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking at a new laptop I'm afraid.

Even if you could replace the motherboard, which is unlikely, the costs of parts and labour would probably be close to the cost of a new laptop anyway.

Comment: But not that expensive for a better laptop